# Flutter rootBundle.load not work unable to load asset

Tags: flutter

this can work:

```
Container(
                width: 60.w,
                height: 20.w,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/imgs/indicator_tab.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

but:

```
await rootBundle.load("assets/imgs/indicator_tab.png");
```

throw Dart Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/imgs/indicator_tab.png, stack trace: #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:224:7)

Comment: Check if you have mentioned folder or file path it in the pubspec.yaml file. and also check the path where you have added you file. Does the file exists over there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/imgs/indicator_tab.png
```

Comment: I hava added it, Otherwise Container won’t work。

Comment: Try to run flutter clean.